# TFS branch structure to use: flat or hierarchic

Tags: tfs, branching-and-merging, alm

I'm wave between using an hierarchic or a flat branch structure.
Hierarchic structure is more logical and is considered the standard.
The cons of hierarchic structure is that I can merge 1.4 DEV2 to 1.5 without touching the 1.4 only with **baseless merge**. 
On the other hand flat structure allows doing **force merge** from any branch to any branch whithout losing change history.

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is opinion, but Flat is better, especially with TFS where it enforces a strict merge hierarchy. You can only merge with a parent or child of the current branch. You can do baseless merges but these often cause more problems than they solve.

Comment: Ultimately you should avoid  branching at all costs in server based source control systems. There are much better practices like feature flags that you can use.

Answer (score 0):

You need to figure out which branch strategy works for your team. Download TFS branching and merging strategies at website below:

https://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/releases

This picture introduces you to some of the branching plans and strategies covered by the guidance and a matrix that allows you to focus on the most relevant plan, you can check it:

[image]

Before branching, it's suggested to read TFS branching and merging strategies first to figure out which branch strategy works for your team. It seems you'll have more branches if you have new version, which is not suggested. In your scenario, it's not needed to have a new branch of 1.5 OG, you can only have one OG branch, when develop test their code in the development branch, he can merge back the code to OG branch and check in. Then each changeset in OG branch is a version.

Comment: Before branching, it's suggested to read TFS branching and merging strategies first to figure out which branch strategy works for your team. In your scenario, It seems you'll have more branches if you have new version, which is not suggested. Actually, it's not needed to have a new branch of 1.5 OG, you can only have one OG branch, when develop test their code in the development branch, he can merge back the code to OG branch and check in. Then each changeset in OG branch is a version.